# Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на картинку (picture box) она открывалась в среднем размере, то есть на половину формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

что мне сделать, что бы при нажатии на картинку (picture box) она открывалась в среднем размере, то есть на половину формы?

Comment: Ну, измените размер этого пикчабокса. Или создайте новый с нужными размерами. Или в `Graphics.DrawImage` задавайте нужные размеры.

Answer (score 0):

Только не забудь назначить Event на Click PictureBox

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private State _state = State.Small;
        private Point _startLocation;
        private Size _startSize;

        private enum State
        {
            Big,
            Small
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _startLocation = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            _startSize = new Size(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_state == State.Small)
            {
                var size = new Size(Width / 2, Height / 2);
                var location = new Point(Width / 2 - size.Width / 2, Height / 2 - size.Height / 2);
                pictureBox1.Size = size;
                pictureBox1.Location = location;
                _state = State.Big;
            }
            else if (_state == State.Big)
            {
                pictureBox1.Size = _startSize;
                pictureBox1.Location = _startLocation;
                _state = State.Small;
            }
        }
    }
```